# dhclient IPv6: Does it perform DAD before accept lease

Tags: linux, ipv6, dhcp

RFC3315 says:

"
   The client SHOULD perform duplicate address detection [17] on each of
   the addresses in any IAs it receives in the Reply message before
   using that address for traffic.  If any of the addresses are found to
   be in use on the link, the client sends a Decline message to the
   server as described in section 18.1.7.
"

But the dhclient on my PC assign duplicated address.
Wireshark shows that there is no DAD check.

How it supposed to work? Did I miss some magic option?

Comment: Belongs on [su]. Also please don't cross-post; questions can be migrated.

Comment: Thanks. What should I do to migrate this question?

Comment: You don't _need_ to do anything; the community should migrate it shortly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The original source code from ISC does not support such requirement for IPv6.
But, it was fixed in Fedora in 2010. See http://www.mirrorservice.org/sites/dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/fedora/linux/releases/20/Fedora/source/SRPMS/d/

But this patch has a bug. It uses ALL options from REQUEST to send DECLINE, however RFC3315 says no Rapid_Commit and no Reconf  options. 
Be careful.

Main idea is to check leased IP for duplication in dhclient-script. If the IP is duplicated script should return 3 otherwise 0.